# Newly Created Tables & Recently Altered Tables in last X days

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to find a ways to below two problems:

1. Tables created in AWS redshift in last X days.
2. Tables which underwent schema changes in last x days.

Please guide me which system owned tables, I can use.

Thanks.

Comment: Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge of Redshift, I don't think any system tables contain a date when tables were created/modified.

You would either need to:

- Capture regular 'snapshots' of tables and their configuration, then do a 'diff' between them, *or*
- Use [STL_DDLTEXT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_DDLTEXT.html) and extract table names from the queries

`STL_DDLTEXT` does contain dates when the queries were run.